# Django REST: ManyToMany field - don't update other records

Tags: python, django

The employees field is a list of users which are employees of the user. Every user can have every user as employee, a user can also be an employee and have employees.

I have a problem where it automatically adds the user as an employee to all the employees added to the user. So when you add user 2 as employee to user 1, it also adds user 1 as employee of user 2.

How can I make it so it doesn't change other records? I simply want to add employees to the user being added.

I'm using Django REST 2.2. The employees field is a ManyToMany field, is this correct for my usage?

[image]

[image]

**users/models.py**

```
class MyUserManager(BaseUserManager):
def create_user(self, email, password=None):
    if not email:
        raise ValueError('Users must have an email address')

    user = self.model(
        email=self.normalize_email(email),
    )

    user.set_password(password)
    user.save(using=self._db)
    return user

def create_superuser(self, email, password):
    user = self.create_user(
        email=self.normalize_email(email),
        password=password,
    )
    user.is_admin = True
    user.is_staff = True
    user.is_superuser = True
    user.save(using=self._db)
    return user

class CustomUser(AbstractBaseUser):
    username = None
    email = models.EmailField(verbose_name='email address', max_length=255, unique=True)
    date_joined = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name='date joined', auto_now_add=True)
    last_login = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name='last login', auto_now=True)
    is_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_superuser = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    is_employee = models.BooleanField('is_employee', default=False)
    employees = models.ManyToManyField("self", related_name='employees', blank=True)

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = []

    objects = MyUserManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email

    def has_perm(self, perm, obj=None):
        return self.is_admin

    def has_module_perms(selfself, app_label):
        return True;
```

**users/serializers.py**

```
class CustomUserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

class Meta:
    model = CustomUser
    fields = ('id', 'email', 'password', 'is_employee', 'employees')

def create(self, validated_data):
    validated_data['password'] = make_password(validated_data.get('password'))
    return super(CustomUserSerializer, self).create(validated_data)

def update(self, instance, validated_data):
    instance.email = validated_data.get('email')
    instance.set_password(validated_data.get('password', instance.password))
    instance.is_employee = validated_data.get('is_employee')
    instance.employees.set(validated_data.get('employees'))
    instance.save()
    return instance
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to set [`ManyToManyField.symmetrical`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField.symmetrical) to `False`

Answer (score 0):

`ManyToMany` relation is wrong for your case. Cause a user can't be an employee of several employers, can only be an employee of a single employer.

So, you should simply create a many-to-one relationship:

```py
class CustomUser(AbstractBaseUser):
    ...
    employer = models.ForeignKey('self', related_name='employees', on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
```

So, each user will have a single `employer` field, and `employees` set. And you can probably get rid of `is_employee` field since you can check if a user is an employee by just checking if `employer` field is set.

Comment: Actually users can have multiple employers in my case. Any idea why adding employees, changes the user model of the employees as well?